# How to use Pandas rolling window with custom function that requires rolled data?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a function that has 3 attributes: `data_string`, `interval`, and `ratio`.

```
def apx_ent(data_string, interval, ratio):
      return np.mean(data_string) * interval * ratio
```

A sample data I have is as follows:

```
0   300.24
1   312.86
2   302.46
3   297.46
4   274.23
5   288.42
6   274.36
7   248.11
8   269.32
9   239.85
10  252.80
11  240.00
12  240.51
13  228.80
14  222.95
15  243.15
```

I'd like to run this custom function on a rolling window, however `data_string` would come from the rolling window itself:

```
df.rolling(3).apply(apx_ent(data_string, 2, 3))
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Expected output:

```
0   NAN
1   NAN
2   NAN
3   0.53
4   0.23
5   0.11
6   0.22
...
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you without an expected output or a reproducible example

Comment: thanks, the expected output is as above, plus a dummy function -- Glad to discuss further - let me know.

Comment: @pepe `df.rolling(3).apply(apx_ent, kwargs={'interval':2, 'ratio':3})`?

Comment: @Yo_Chris this outputs the same value for each row—doesn't look like it applies the rolled data incrementally

Comment: @pepe It did not output the same value for me...

Comment: @pepe [join the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211650/chat-for-pepe)